# How to make v-select2-component use select2.full.min.js file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jquery-select2

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-select2-component in my vuejs project.

I have to use it at many places, at some places with search box and at some places without search box.
It accepts 'minimumResultsForSearch' in case if we don't want to use search box, but that functionality is only available when we import select2.full.min.js.

I imported select2.full.min.js in file but those changes are made in node modules but I can't push node modules to git repository.

Any alternate solution to this?

Comment: Why does this have the vue-select tag when it's asking about an entirely different component to https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-select?

Comment: @JohnY Updated. Thanks for pointing out. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a configurable [`settings`](https://github.com/godbasin/vue-select2/tree/npm-publish-code#options) option that allows you to do just that.

```vue
<Select2 :options="myOptions" :settings="mySettings" />
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    myOptions: [],

    mySettings: {
      minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
    }
  }
}
```

References:

- https://github.com/godbasin/vue-select2#options
- https://select2.org/searching#hiding-the-search-box

Comment: As I mentioned, I have already used this but it isn't possible to use minimumResultsForSearch without select2.full.min.js whereas the https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-select2-component module which includes select2.js instead of the select2 full file.

Comment: @Rider If you look at the source code, it does seem to have this [`settings`](https://github.com/godbasin/vue-select2/blob/npm-publish-code/src/Select2.vue#L36) prop shipped with the library. Not sure how you are not getting it.

Comment: I am getting settings prop but when I pass minimuResultsForSearch, it doesn't work. I googled and found that minimumResultsForSearch, dropdownCssClass,etc require select2.full.min.js to be used but the npm module I mentioned uses select2.js but when I changed in module file to use select2.full.min.js it worked. So, I would like to know is there any way node module changes can be pushed to git?

Comment: Well that's weird, `select2.js` also seems to include this specific [setting](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/develop/dist/js/select2.js#L4988).